# Do NOT let transaction rollback for a particular type of RuntimeException

Tags: spring, spring-transactions, runtimeexception

Hi is there a way to let spring transaction NOT rollback after I throw a particular kind of RuntimeException?

I have a class called CustomException extends RuntimeException, I want to do sth before throwing it. But because of the rollback, whatever is done by doSth() is rolled back.

```
doSth();
throw new CustomException();
```

I can manage this by changing CustomException from extending RuntimeException to Exception so that it becomes a checked exception.

However after doing this, I'll have to add `throws CustomException` to all methods that will call this block of code. So just wondering if there's a more graceful way

Comment: Is doSth() part of the same class? Also changing to extend from Exception will also result in rollback if I I understand your question correctly

Comment: yes it's of the same class. By extending from Exception and make it a checked exception, rollback should not happen anymore as I tried, as spring only rollback RuntimeExceptino by default I believe

Comment: That is true. Initially you extended from RuntimeException which made me think a rollback is required when the exception condition happens. If in your case , no rollback is required , but the exception should propogate back , solution from _Niraj Jha_ should work.  If that is not what you require , could you please update the question accordingly ?

Comment: do you mean if I extends from RuntimeException then Niraj's method won't work? However it worked for me. Could you provide more explanations? I don't really need the exception to propogate back, that's why I want to keep extending from RuntimeException by using Niraj's way

Comment: Niraj's solution would work . I understood that your requirement was a rollback on exception and only the changes from doSth() should persist. That way changing from RuntimeException to Exception and still doing a rollback will also result in the doSth() to not persist. My comment was on that context . Hope this clarifies

Comment: do you mean "changing from RuntimeException to Exception" and still "forcefully" doing a rollback? because my understanding is that after changing it to extending from Exception, there will be no rollback unless I call it specifically

Comment: yes . as explained I overcomplicated your question. and your understanding about the rollback is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use noRollbackFor attribute of @Transactional.

```
@Transactional(noRollbackFor = customException.class)
```

Comment: yes tried and worked. I know the property "rollbackFor", should have thought of this. thanks @Niraj

Comment: Welcome, please don't forget to see all the attributes for any of the annotations, it's really helpful.